# Spanning sets question

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following subspaces which are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$V = \{(2a,b,0)\ :\ a,b \in \mathbb{R} \},$$

$$W = \{(a+c,c-b,3c)\ :\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \},$$

$$X = \{(4a+d,a+2b,c-b)\ :\ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \},$$

How come $V$ only needs 2 vectors to form a spanning set when $(2a,b,0)$ has three components, and whilst $(a+c,c-b,3c)$ and $(4a+d,a+2b,c-b)$ both have three components, $W$ needs three vectors but $X$ needs four to form a spanning set?

Comment: V does not span all of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: The point is that every vector in $V$ can be written (uniquely, in fact) as $a(2,0,0)+b(0,1,0)$, every vector in $W$ can be written as $a(1,0,0)+b(0,-1,0)+c(1,1,3)$, etc. The number of components does not matter.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Does the number of components ever matter when forming a spanning set?

Comment: @user326441: That is not the right question to ask. It seems you need to look more closely at the definition of a spanning set for a vector space. We say a set of vectors $S$ spans a vector space $V$ if *every* vector $v$ in V is equal to a linear combination of vectors in $S$. (For a spanning set, we do not require that this linear combination be unique.) So, if you are looking for a spanning set of your $V$, you should look for a way to write every vector in $V$ as a linear combination of other vectors. Your definition of $V$ makes the solution immediately obvious.

Comment: Okay I'll go back over it. Thanks :)